# Creating login app and getting ModelNotFoundException error in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new to PHP and Laravel. I am making a Laravel login app which prints "success" after comparing the entered value and database value.

My problem is: when both value are matched it prints "success" but when they are not matched it shows **ModelNotFoundException** .

I have created an exception for this but again same error occurs.

Thank you in advance!

Here is my route.php code

**route.php**

```
Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@register');
Route::post('register/show', 'RegisterController@show');
Route::post('register/store', 'RegisterController@store');
Route::get('register/login', 'RegisterController@login');
```

Here is my register controller which get value from **index.blade.php** and from database named **registers** which has two columns **username** and **password**

**RegisterController.php**

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Register;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller {

    public function register()
    {
        return view('register.index');
    }
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Request::all();
        Register::create($input); 
        return redirect('register');
    }

    public function show()
    {




        try
        {
            $result2 = Request::get('username');
            $result = Register::where('username',  $result2)->firstOrFail();
            return view('register.show', compact('result','result2'));
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) 
        {
            return "login fail" . redirect('register/login');
        }

    }

    public function login()
    {
        return view('register.login');
    }
}
```

**Register.php**

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Register extends Model {

        protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];


    }
```

**CreateRegistersTable**

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRegistersTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('registers', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('registers');
    }

}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')
@section('login')

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'register/store']) !!}

{!!Form::label('username','Name:')!!}
{!!Form::text('username', null)!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('password','Password:')!!}
{!!Form::text('password', null)!!}
{!!Form::submit('submit')!!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

**login.blade.php**

```
 @extends('master')
@section('register')

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'register/show']) !!}

{!!Form::label('username','Name:')!!}
{!!Form::text('username', null)!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('password','Password:')!!}
{!!Form::text('password', null)!!}
{!!Form::submit('submit')!!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

** show.blade.php **

```
@extends('master')
@section('show')

<?php 
if( $result->username == $result2  )
{
    echo "success";
}

?>
@stop
```

Comment: Have you mentioned the table name in Register.php as it is a Model? like, protected $table = 'registers';

Comment: I don't know if you want to do this or not. But there is already a User class implementing all needed Auth controls and AuthController.
Try /auth/login :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the error trapping logic to your app/Exceptions/Handler.php file?

Check out http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent ; specifically where it states:

**Retrieving A Model By Primary Key Or Throw An Exception**

Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. To do this, you may use the firstOrFail method:

```
$model = User::findOrFail(1);

$model = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();
```

Doing this will let you catch the exception so you can log and display an error page as necessary. To catch the ModelNotFoundException, **add some logic to your app/Exceptions/Handler.php file**.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

public function render($request, Exception $e)
  {
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
    {
        // Custom logic for model not found...
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the adding the logic to your Handler.php file?